# Regex in Splunk Log to search

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

I have Splunk logs , whose entry looks as below:

```
15/01/2020
10:34:29.076    
{ [-]
   app_module: testmodule
   environment: XXXX
   level:  INFO
   logger_name:                      project.stats
   message: Query execution time: [1222] app ID: [TEST] for user: [jhhsakjhsa]
   thread_name:    catalina-exec-371
   timestamp: 2020-01-15T05:04:29,076
   x-request-id: hdkhwqkjdhwqhdwqdo908109328182eh
}
Show as raw text
host = <host>,worker, Splunk--idx-d-i-0xssaxx4d0f95a8timestamp = 2020-01-15T05:04:29,076
```

I need to make query where query execution time is in 4 digits. We have query execution time as log statement in message field in splunk log (**Query execution time: [1222]**)

What will be query for same.

Answer (score 0):

The following will create a new field, called `query_exec_time`

```
rex field=_raw "Query execution time: \[(?<query_exec_time>\d+)\]"
```

So your search can look like the following

```
index=<...> | rex field=_raw "Query execution time: \[(?<query_exec_time>\d+)\]" | where query_exec_time > 999
```

Alternatively, you can also use `regex`

```
index=<...> | regex _raw="Query execution time: \[\d{4})\]"
```

Comment: where i will create rex field=_raw "Query execution time: [(?<query_exec_time>\d+)]"

Comment: index=<...> | regex _raw="Query execution time: [\d{4})]" is not giving required result

Comment: try now, i have escaped some characters